# "Rails by Example" authentication implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication, cookies

In Michael Hart's book this code is used to implement authentication:

```
module SessionsHelper
def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt] #permanent
    # -alternatively-
    # cookies.signed[:remember_token]={
    #   :value => [user.id, user.salt],
    #   expires => some_time.from_now
    # }

    current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    return @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

private
    def user_from_remember_token
        #passes array of length two as a parameter -- first slot contains ID,
        #second contains SALT for encryption
        User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
        #ensures return of a double array in the event that
        #cookies.signed[:remember_token] is nil.
        cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
    end

    end
```

It does it's job very well, I can either log in for an infinite amount of time, or for a limited period of time as I wish.
But it has a downside, cookies are stored on the client and they dont go away even if the browser is closed

Now I was wondering, since rails sessions get destroyed after a browser is closed, how would I combine them and the cookies presented here to implement authentication with the following characteristics:

-- if a user logs in, 
   the data should be stored in a session
   so that after a user closes his browser they get logged of

-- if  a user logs in, with a 'remember me' checkbox selected
    their data should be stored in a cookie with a long expiration date

What would be a take on this that remains secure and simple?
I googled on the web and found nothing recent enough (Rails 3) that
could guide me in the right direction.
I was thinking of creating 2 separate modules for sessions and cookies and fire their respective sign_in methods in the controller whether a remember_me param was present or not, but that would seem a lot of duplication.

PS I am not looking into any authentication gems to provide this functionality, id prefer to implement it on my own.

Thanks

Comment: I realise you say that you're not looking for authentication gems, which is fine if you're simply trying to learn how to do this kind of things. If you're planning to use this in production, however, I would very much suggest you use an established solution for security purposes.

Comment: you might check some available solutions source code on github to find possible solutions